# I can see Urdu language in DB but not on on home page

Tags: mysql-5.0

I have Urdu language not-for-profit news website. I had old database in MySQL4.0 but now the server has updated the database and it is now MySQL5.0.
My website was working well in earlier database but now text shows as question marks. But I can see the news with Urdu text in phpMyAdmin.
Can somebody tell me what is problem?

Thanks,
Kazmi

Comment: Kazim have u solved the issue? I am also facing the same problem? please post as answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your character sets set to utf-8 which I believe should work for urdu.

you may need to call this mysql statement before any query:

```
SET NAMES 'UTF-8'
```

more information about it at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html